# Discretize second order derivative using the finite difference scheme

Tags: finite-differences

I have some problems in Discretize the second order derivative of this equation 
[image]

after I find u(x) by integrating it, I have problem in discretize it ,, I'm not mathematical person and I try to read a lot .

any help ?!

Answer (score 6):

A discrete form of the second derivative is 
$$u''(x) \approx \frac{u(x+h)-2u(x)+u(x-h)}{h^2}\tag{1}$$
Partition  the interval $[0,1]$ with uniformly distributed points $0=x_0<x_1<\dots <x_n=1$ and denote $u_j=u(x_j)$. Since $h=1/n$, the difference scheme for your equation takes the form
$$  u_{j+1}-2u_j+u_{j-1} = -\frac{1}{n^2},\quad j=1,\dots,n-1 \tag{2}$$
Since $u_0=1$ and $u_n=2$ are known, the equations (2) form a linear system of $n-1$ equations with $n-1$ unknowns. Its solution is an approximation to $u$.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe some users need help for the derivation of eq. (1) in the answer above.

One can proceed as follows: In the continuum case
\begin{equation}
p(x):=\frac{du}{dx}:=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{u(x+h)-u(x)}{h}
\end{equation}
So for the second derivative
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}=\frac{dp}{dx}=\lim_{j\rightarrow 0} \frac{p(x+j)-p(x)}{j} =\lim_{j\rightarrow 0} \frac{\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{u(x+h+j)-u(x+j)}{h}-\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{u(x+h)-u(x)}{h}}{j}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{ u(x+2h)-2u(x+h)+u(x)}{h^2}  
\end{equation}
In the discrete version, $h$ becomes a small but finite parameter. Shifting once by $h$ yields the result.
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\approx \frac{ u(x+h)-2u(x)+u(x-h)}{h^2}  
\end{equation}

Closed formulas for higher discrete derivatives are given in [the Wikipedia-article on finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences).

Comment: You mean $+u(x)$ and $+u(x-h)$ in the last two equations.

Comment: Thanks @Kagaratsch , I corrected that